# Why does the following simple Haskell function give slightly strange answers?

Tags: haskell

```
(%?) :: Int -> (Int -> Int) -> Int
x %? f = f x

m :: Int -> Int
m v = v %? \z -> z * 2 %? \z -> z + 3 %? \x -> x + z
```

or simpler

```
p :: Int -> Int
p v = v %? \z -> z * 2 %? \z -> z + 3
```

e.g, p 4 = 20

Comment: This looks a lot like homework...

Answer (score 2):

`%?` has too high precedence and is left-associative, so `v %? \z -> z * 2 %? \z -> z + 3` is the same as `v %? \z -> z * (2 %? \z -> z + 3)`.

If you want `%?` to behave like `$` use `infixr 0 %?`, so it has the same precedence and associativity as `$`.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it would help to know what you were *expecting* it to do. But perhaps it would help to put some explicit parentheses in `p`:

```
q :: Int -> Int
q v = v %? (\z -> z * (2 %? (\z -> z + 3)))
```

Perhaps you were you expecting something more like this:

```
p2 :: Int -> Int
p2 v = v %? (\z -> (z * 2) %? (\z -> z + 3))
```

It's probably a good idea to add an `infix` declaration for any operators you declare, to avoid this sort of confusion. Arithmetic operators have mid-high precedence, but given what the function does you probably want very low precedence anyway.

As an aside--lambdas extend all the way to the right, but I'm guessing that's not what's tripping you up.